# Is there a hashmap implementation that uses a caching scheme?

Tags: java, hashmap

I swear that in the past I had seen something about a hashmap implementation using some type of caching but when I was reading up today on how hashmaps are implemented in java, it was just simply a table with linked lists. Let me go deeper in what I mean.

From what I read today, hashmap in java is essentially like so

1. There exists an array simply called "table" where each index of the array is the hashcode. The value of the array is the first element of the linked list for that hashcode.
2. When you try to retrieve an object from the hashmap using the key, the key is transformed into a hashcode which is applied as the index of the "table" to then go to the linkedlist to iterate and find the correct object corresponding to the key.

But what I had read before was something different than this. What I had read was when you retrieve an object from the hashmap using the key, the corresponding bucket is cached so that when you retrieve another object from the hashmap from the same bucket, you are using the cache. But when you retrieve an object from a different bucket, the other bucket is cached instead.

Did I just completely misunderstand something in the past and invent something in my head, or is there something like this that might have confused me?

Comment: I can imagine a hash map that moved elements to the front of their lists so they'd be found faster next time. It'd be a tricky and questionable optimization, though, because now reading would cause updates. That means contention in a multithreaded scenario, needing to take locks or do complicated lock-free updates, etc.

Comment: Hashmaps are resized automatically to reduce the chance of two objects ending in the same bucket. So the linkedlist is typically only one or two elements, removing the need for any caching.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of that.

First of all: the "table" array has only a certain size so the hascode is not used directly. From the HashMap source `tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]`

Maybee you are mixing it up with the `LinkedHashMap` which keeps track of the element accesses:

```java
    void afterNodeAccess(Node<K,V> e) { // move node to last
        LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> last;
        if (accessOrder && (last = tail) != e) {
            LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> p =
                (LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V>)e, b = p.before, a = p.after;
            p.after = null;
            if (b == null)
                head = a;
            else
                b.after = a;
            if (a != null)
                a.before = b;
            else
                last = b;
            if (last == null)
                head = p;
            else {
                p.before = last;
                last.after = p;
            }
            tail = p;
            ++modCount;
        }
    }
```

This behavior is usefull if you are implementing a LRU (Least recently used) cache. A LRU cache removes the elements that have not been requested for the longest period, once the cache reached its maximum size.